# Assignment of struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
    extern struct aStruct aStruct_table[4];
    
int main()
{
        aStruct_table[0].val1 = 0;
        aStruct_table[0].val2 = 0x0;
        aStruct_table[0].val3 = 0x130;
        aStruct_table[1].val1 = 1;
        aStruct_table[1].val2 = 0x140;
        aStruct_table[1].val3 = 0x860;
        aStruct_table[1].val1 = 4;
        aStruct_table[1].val2 = 0x2050;
        aStruct_table[1].val3 = 0x1950;
        aStruct_table[1].val1 = 7;
        aStruct_table[1].val2 = 0x6000;
        aStruct_table[1].val3 = 0x666;
}
```

Is there another way to assign the struct array without having so much code?
Maybe sth like

```
    extern struct aStruct aStruct_table[4] = {{0,0x0,0x130},
                                             {1,0x140,0x860},
                                             {4,0x2050,0x1950},
                                             {7,0x6000,0x666}};
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up assignment and initialization, I guess.

In modern C, AKA C99, the best way to do initialization of a `struct` is with "designated initializers"

```
struct aStruct A = { .val1 = 0, .val2 = 0x0A };
```

and the syntax for arrays of structs is just to repeat that:

```
struct aStruct B[] = {
   { .val1 = 0, .val2 = 0x0A },
   { .val1 = 2, .val2 = 0x0B }
};
```

But you shouldn't do it with the `extern` in front. That one is for the forward declaration in the header file without the initialization part.

If you really meant assignment, for `struct` you can use "compound literals

```
A = (struct aStruct){ .val1 = 0, .val2 = 0x0A };
```

but as you probably know there is no assignment syntax for arrays.

Comment: an "assignment syntax for arrays"

Comment: You mean there is one? Try it. As I say there is **initialization** syntax for arrays, my variable `B` shows that. But there is no such thing as assignment to arrays.

Comment: OK, I mixed up between initialization and assignment, but you can initialize particular indices and skip others. Bah, nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is perfectly legal to do that.

With C99 initializers it can be even clearer:

```
extern struct aStruct aStruct_table[4] = {
    [0] = {
        .val1 = 0,
        .val2 = 0x0,
    },
    [1] = {
// etc etc
```

Comment: @JensGustedt I forgot the dots to struct initalizers, apart from that it is perfectly valid!